# CSS Backdrop and static sprites

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about a CSS dilemma I am stuck with, I tried using various methods but nothing is really working the way I want it. I want a simple backdrop image, and then place images randomly on the backdrop. The trick is, it should stay where it is suppose to be no matter what the resolution.

At the moment this is the code I am using that is failing me :(

```
<div class="Backdrop"><img src="/Images/Backdrop.png" />                
<div class="Ninja"><div class="IE7">(7)Alignment<img src="/Images/miAverage.png" alt=(2)A2" /></div>
<div class="IE8">(7)Alignment<img src="/Images/miBad.png" alt=(1)B1" />
</div>
```

the CSS looks as follows:

```
    .BackDrop {        
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#999999;
}

.IE7{ visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 300px; left: 200px; }
.IE8{ visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 300px; left: 400px; }
```

Please note this code was mostly generated with MVC.

Comment: Closing your div tags might help. Also without a working example is very difficult to imagine what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: You forgot a number of quotes; look at the syntax highlighting. Also, class names are case sensitive.